# Not able to install nodejs in ubuntu command line

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, nodejs

I have tried this: `sudo apt install nodejs`

Getting Error this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Depends: python-minimal but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is correct.

Run the next command to find out what release version you use:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release | grep RELEASE
```

Then follow one of the next links to change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

[19.10 sources.list](https://gist.github.com/malikalichsan/860b8134a74c65a394efe09711d0b95f)
[18.04 sources.list](https://gist.github.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1)
[16.04 sources.list](https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1)

You could backup your old `sources.list` file by `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bk` and create new one pasting there content from one of the provided links.

Then do

```
sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt install npm nodejs node-abbrev node-ansi node-rimraf
```

and try again.

Also make sure there's no suspicious repositories under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder that could also contain `nodejs` of newer version that do not contain required dependencies.

Comment: Not able to save in /etc/apt/sources.list the 18.04 sources.list...permission denied

Comment: use `sudo` command before your editor. For example `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` or `sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: successfully installed nodejs version 10.19.0.....after i installed npm with link sudo apt install npm.... it return this error (written below) after that i checked npm version it shows 6.13.4

Comment: The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi (>= 0.3.0-2) but it is not going to be insta
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to b....................
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.